# problems with creating a raid 5 array

Tags: raid, mdadm, disk-utility

when ever I try creating a RAID setup with the disck utility it gives me the following error:

Error creating RAID array: Error spawning command-line `mdadm --create /dev/md127 --run --chunk 512 --level raid6 --name "storage" --raid-devices 4 "/dev/sda" "/dev/sdc" "/dev/sdd" "/dev/sdf"': Failed to execute child process "mdadm" (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8) (udisks-error-quark, 0)

It appears that I am missing the mdadm library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread after searching for exactly the same error.  The only difference is that I am trying to create a RAID10 array and install Ubuntu, but I don't think that should matter much.

The answer I found is painfully simple..."Failed to execute child process 'mdadm'(No such file of directory)..." is the giveaway.  The package mdadm is not installed.

So ... I'm using the Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 Live CD and did "sudo apt-get install mdadm"

Happy RAID creating!  My RAID is sync'ing after building using the Disk Utility.  I hope this works for you.

Cheers!